# Computer refuses to accept wifi password, sometimes

Tags: networking

I have been using Ubuntu for the last several months and for the most part I have been having a good time with it. That is except for one issue. As is implied in the title my Wi-Fi just won't connect. It will ask for my password, think for a bit then ask for it again and again and again on and on. the weird things is that it will ever once in a while connect until I turn the computer off again and then it will stop working again (twice it  connected for a brief bit then disconnect). There is nothing i can think of that will consistently get it to work. Turning the Wi-Fi on and off, resetting the computer, resetting the network manager itself absolutely nothing.

the Wi-Fi password is correct, I can connect to it with other devices and I can get the computer to connect to a data hot stop on my phone. I remember the computer working on Ethernet when I first set it up, however I don't have ready accesses to it where my desk is so this is not an option. Everything is up to date as far as updates are concerned. Thank you in advance for any help that is offered and/or supplied.
(note I have typed this on my laptop becuse of mobile data limits and I am using the 22.04.1 Lts version of ubuntu) (as asked my card is a Intel corporation Wi-Fi 6 ax210/ax211/ax411 1 60mhz [8086:2725] (rev 1a); both card and wifi routher are Wi-Fi 6)

Comment: Welcome to AU. Before anything else check router's wireless settings: Encryption should be WPA2-AES or newer and no WPA/WPA2 mixed mode.

Comment: If the aforementioned settings are the recommended ones then we need a lot more info. Please [edit] the question and add Ubuntu release/version and at least the WiFi device you're using.

Comment: I have no idea how i would figure out what wifi device I have. My wifi card came in build with the motherboard. I will edit to clarify with version I am on.

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` to identify the hardware. And, of course, check the router FIRST.